# Object pool pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript

Are there special considerations for implementing [the object pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) in Javascript? Does anyone know of some existing implementations, beside Matt Snider's [example](http://mattsnider.com/object-pool-pattern-in-javascript/) for which I could benchmark performance?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be useful in JavaScript, as the Garbagge Collector is used to work with short living objects, and optimizes them away. If you don't want GC, you can use WebAssembly.

Comment: @JonasWilms: typically pools are used to control the number of resources that are limited externally. Javascript runtime's GC has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @JonasWilms Java also has a garbage collector, but the use of object pools for performance reasons is quite ubiquitous. The problem with GC is that it creates "hickups" from the point of the user, when it needs to do massive cleanup of objects created in tight loops. To avoid that, you use the object pool pattern where you just re-use the same objects to avoid hitting the GC. I am just wondering if there are existing implementations to learn from and if JS/Spidermonkey/WebKit has special considerations.

Comment: You assume that "short living objects" always cause a stop the world GC. That is not the case. I know that they are commonly used in Java, but from my (opinionated) point of view: I had some trouble with Java's garbage collector but not yet any trouble with the JavaScript GCs. Maybe thats because I've never written any Game engine in JS (but in Java)

Comment: [Related: V8 Orinoco](https://v8.dev/blog/trash-talk)

Comment: @wiktor I don't get you.

Comment: @JonasWilms: A typical use case for the object pool - controlling the number of concurrently used connections to an [external database](https://blog.pythian.com/sql-server-understanding-and-controlling-connection/). But there are other [use cases](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/371995/what-are-some-use-cases-for-the-object-pool-design-pattern) even in [Javascript](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious-connection-pool). How would that be related to the Garbage Collector?

Comment: @wiktor well as the OP stated that he needs performance I assumed that we are talking about object pools used during rendering, the main problem there is that creating a lot of objects causes GC to kick in and cause lags. I agree with you that the question could also be understood as being about object pools in a broader sense, but for smaller pool sizes the implementation is trivial.

Comment: @TheNimbleSurfer: haven't you stumbled upon the [Static Memory Javascript](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/static-mem-pools/) technique? The linked post contains references to multiple example implementations you could try.

Comment: @WiktorZychla That article ("Static memory...") was actually linked to in the article I linked to above, I didn't spot the references at the end. Thanks!

Comment: @TheNimbleSurfer: indeed, the article is linked there, at the end of the article you linked to. I've missed that in the first place and that's why I wasn't aware you need the pool for this particular scenario.